# Need Feedback on a Scheduled Job

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow, scheduled-job

I am trying to schedule a job in Salesforce that does not require any user interaction.  Basically the quote object would need to have the status (picklist) updated once the date is 30 days past the expiration date of the quote.

Right now, I have a time based workflow in place once a user edits the record that will automatically change the status.  However, if the user does not actually edit, I need the record updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

If you set your time based workflow to get set up at insert as well, or rather when the expiration date is added/updated, won't it work even if the user never updates the quote later on ?

Comment: hmmm I did not think of that approach!  I will try it and see if it works.  Thank you so much for the feedback.